# Adding loading state on button - Reactjs Shopify Polaris

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I am trying to add loading state on button when user clicks **login** until login function return something.

Simple button is like:

```
<Button primary onClick={this.handleSubmit}></Button>
```

And loading button is like:

```
<Button primary onClick={this.handleSubmit} Loading></Button>
```

So i want to add `Loading` attribute into button when user clicks on it but i get error on following code:

Here is button code:

```
<Button primary onClick={this.handleSubmit} {this.state.buttonloading}>Login</Button>
```

Error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ... (64:61)
AT: <Button primary onClick={this.handleSubmit} {this.state.buttonloading}>Login</Button>
                                                ^
```

How I am suppose to add **Loading** attribute in Button component

PS. I am using [Shopify Polaris Components](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/get-started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
<Button primary onClick={this.handleSubmit} Loading={this.state.buttonloading}>Login</Button>
```

Comment: "Loading" is called "props". In "Button " component it call "this.props.Loading", if true then set Loading in Component Button. They use short syntax "Loading" instead of Loading={true}. Sorry for my bad english